# CSS font-family doesn't work for dropdown

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, font-family

I'm working with a form management system provided by an external provider (no support). You can adjust the presentation of the form via CSS. So I would like to use another font.

```
.CXHeader *,
.XItem.XSelect.XDropDown *,
.CXFooter *,
.CXPage,
.XPage *,
.xm-form.modern * {
    font-family: 'AlwynNew';
}
```

I defined the font using `@font-face`, like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family:'AlwynNew';
src: url('ressource?mid=8&name=AlwynNew-Rg.otf') format('opentype');
font-weight:  normal;
font-style:  normal;
}
```

The thing is, it works everywhere, expect for the dropdown list. But the code should be right.

**What I tried so far**

I tested it with `color` and `background-color` and these two work fine for the dropdown list. When the list isn't dropped down, it shows the right font. But if it's dropped down, colors are right, font is wrong.

I also tried `!important` (see mmh4all's Post) like that:

```
font-family: 'AlwynNew' !important;
```

It doesn't make a difference.

*Answer to Hans Sagita's Post*

First I tried:

```
*:after{
    font-family: AlwynNew !important;
}
```

It didn't work. I tried `.dropdown::after` and `.XDropdown::after,` anyway, didn't work as well.

**Code inspector**

I also used the "code inspector" of the browser or however you call it. The names of the classes are correct and there is nothing overwriting the font.

[image]
(Translation: "Keine Schriftarten für das gewählte Element verwendet": "No fonts used for the selected element".)

And these are the fonts used showed by the code inspector when a `<select>` element is selected.

[image: fonts used code inspector]
(Translation: "Verwendete Schriftart": Fonts used;
"Alle Schriftarten der Seite": All fonts of the page.)

But again: When I select an option element, the font tab says: "No fonts used for the selected element".

How do I set the font also for the `<option>` elements?

Comment: Can you add your HTML too please so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Adam: I included a screenshot of the browser code inspector.

Comment: do you use other fonts in your html?

Comment: just to make things very clear.. in the element inspector you are showing the select element matching the selector `.xm-form.modern * {}`  getting its `font-family` set as `AlwynNew`. I suppose that's the font family you called `MyFont` in the general example on top. Anyway that's the font you'll see for the ***selected*** option on the select element. The `font-family` set for the options will be the font used when you open the dropdown menu. And that selector you used should address them all anyway...

Comment: However can you see the ***computed styles*** for both the select and option elements? does the `font-family` still match? and for the sake of curiosity what do you see in the ***fonts tab*** (that shows the actually rendered font for the element)?

Comment: @DiegoD: You assumed correctly: I called AlwynNew MyFont. When I pick an option element in the code inspector, it also shows me that the font-family AlwynNew applies. What do you mean by "fonts tab"? I used Firefox so far, do you recommand another browser?

Comment: the font-family is only part of the story. As you know it gets mapped to the actual fonttype that will be used (that's the fontface game mapping each fontfamily to an actual font file). So when css-wise you see the font-family property set you are not still sure which font actually got used for rendering. This is the fonts tab I was talking about before: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/page_inspector/how_to/edit_fonts/

Comment: Anyway reading again your sentence: _"I tested it with color and background-color and these two work fine for the dropdown list. When the list isn't dropped down, it shows the right font. But if it's dropped down, colors are right, font is wrong."_ what you are seeing in the inspector matches the element behaviour. The font is getting applied to the select actually because you are seeing it happening. The font applied to the options when you open the dropdown, will depend on how ***option***s have font-family. So check it out in your inspector expanding the `<select>` and seeing its children

Comment: @DiegoD: I added a screenshot of the fonts tab. When I expand the select-element, I see this e.g. `<option title="" value="1" data-col0="Januar" data-col1="Jan" data-col2="1" data-idx="1" id="xi-sel-4_1">Januar</option>`. And in the computed styles it still says AlwynNew. In the fonts tab it says: "No fonts used for the selected element." Interessting. How do I set the font family for options?

Comment: since in your elements inspector screenshot you have the rule `.xm-form.modern *` applied to the `select` I expect that also the options were styled like that unless they have a rule that overrides that for the options. Some people in their answer reccomended to use `!important` in your rule. It's not clear if you did or not.. anyway the next step for you was checking for sure how the options were styled. It's what I asked you just before. Expand(!) the `select` in your element inspector and see how ***those*** (options) are styled

Comment: @DiegoD: I updated the screenshot and added `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tajawal:wght@200;300;400;500;700;800;900&display=swap");
```

import font family like this
after that put the font family name

```
font-family: 'Tajawal';
```

Comment: I added to my question how I "imported" the font. It already works fine for everything except the options of a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Use **!important** to your font **or** remove **!important** from the previous Fonts and make sure the css class is after your general font class

```
font-family: 'MyFont' !important;
```

Example:

```
body {
 font-family: 'FirstFont' !important;
}

.dropdown {
 font-family: 'SecondFont';
}
```

in this case SecondFont will not override the first one

```
body {
 font-family: 'FirstFont';
}

.dropdown {
 font-family: 'SecondFont';
}
```

but in this case it will override

or you can use **!important** for the second one too and it will work as well

Comment: Thank you, but !important didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this one first, just to check it is applied to the dropdown ?(this should be applicable to all UI)

```
*:after{
    font-family: AlwynNew !important;
}
```

if it is work you can try to

```
.dropdown::after{
    font-family: AlwynNew !important;
}
```

Hope Works, thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your first suggestion, but it didn't work. I tried the second one as well, also no difference.